PGAdmin doesn't dump roles?
I am new to backing up and restoring databases, but it looks like pgadmin doesn't create roles when you go to backup a database.
Is this correct or am I crazy?

Roles are global to the cluster, not the database. You need to use pg_dumpall to get them. -r --roles-only Dump only roles, no databases or tablespaces. For pgAdmin4 see Backup Globals.

Duplicate of: Postgres restore missing privileges.
